# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/staxex/XMLStreamReaderEx

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am getting an exception, but it isn't a code problem, it is a settings/dependencies problem.

I have a work and home computer.  The project files are synced via OneDrive.  Both computers are running Mac OSX 10.11.4, jdk1.8.0_66.jdk and IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1

The code works at my work but at home I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/staxex/XMLStreamReaderEx
    at com.sun.xml.stream.buffer.stax.StreamReaderBufferCreator.storeElementAndChildren(StreamReaderBufferCreator.java:195)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.buffer.stax.StreamReaderBufferCreator.storeDocumentAndChildren(StreamReaderBufferCreator.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.buffer.stax.StreamReaderBufferCreator.store(StreamReaderBufferCreator.java:160)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.buffer.stax.StreamReaderBufferCreator.create(StreamReaderBufferCreator.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.buffer.MutableXMLStreamBuffer.createFromXMLStreamReader(MutableXMLStreamBuffer.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.buffer.XMLStreamBuffer.createNewBufferFromXMLStreamReader(XMLStreamBuffer.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.addressing.WSEndpointReference.<init>(WSEndpointReference.java:183)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.addressing.WSEndpointReference.<init>(WSEndpointReference.java:175)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.addressing.AddressingVersion.<init>(AddressingVersion.java:443)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.addressing.AddressingVersion.<init>(AddressingVersion.java:72)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.addressing.AddressingVersion$1.<init>(AddressingVersion.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.addressing.AddressingVersion.<clinit>(AddressingVersion.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.security.addressing.policy.WsawAddressingPrefixMapper.<clinit>(WsawAddressingPrefixMapper.java:63)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
......
```

I have stax2-api.jar and stax-api.jar in the library/provided of my project. I have VPN'd to work and looked at the project setup and can't see any differences.

How can I work out what the difference is between the two machines to get the code to work at home?

Comment: Use stax2-api.jar jar only. remove the dependency of stax-api.jar. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding, that didn't work, and also the suggestion does not account for why it works @ work, but not @ home.

Comment: Are you using apache commons exec jar in your pom.xml?

Comment: locate pom.xml reveals no files in the project or java directories on either computers.

Comment: are JRE_HOME and JDK_HOME both added in your system? Please check.  JRE_HOME should be including /bin. Please have a try

Comment: not sure if it is correct, but both ~.bash_login have export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)  nothing about JRE_HOME or JDK_HOME  how do i set that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110256/discussion-between-pgee70-and-skywalker).

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what was wrong, but re-installing a newer version of the JDK fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happends because there are conflicting jar files with same class but different implementations(think about different versions). Try removing all jars one by one until you stop receiving this error(target XML parser libraries - jaxws-rt ....etc).

Answer (score 0):

in my case, with almost exactly the same scenario (albeit on Windows and Netbeans 8.1), the culprit was finally the fact that the JDK platform I was using had Metro/WSIT JAX-WS implementation sitting in %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\endorsed folder, while the project I was trying to run was using Apache CXF JAX-WS implementation, so some dependencies like STAX was overridden by the libraries in the endorsed folder, even though I was including those dependencies with my JAR.

i was able to trace that supplying -verbose:class option to the JVM while debugging and checking the class loading process just before the error. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same issue, Above post helped me at least go near the error and understand it.

And after some analysis. I just upgraded the Jaws-rt  Jar version it resolved my issue.

By the time I using Jaws-rt jar below maven dependency i used.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```